# Roundcube YetiForce

Tags: php, linux

Доброго времени суток. Поставил YetiForce, хотел настроить почту. Но вот не задача CRM не хочет скачивать roundcube. Поставил через apt, копирнул файлы в папку где должен быть модуль, теперь пишет "нужно обновить" а опять же не обновляет. Попробовал просто из библиотеки CRM копировать, при обновлении вычищает папку. Понятия не имею как установить из файла.

Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Короче я вообще ламер.
Нужно было просто с github скачать для yeti, закинуть в папку где он должен лежать в crm. Дать права на www-data. И всё! 3 дня сидел...